# How do I crop everything in Video Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have made a video composed of several videos with transitions etc, but they all have a 80px black strip on the top and bottom, and I'd like to remove it (so that the video's height is 160px less). **How do I crop the video?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can group your clips in to a **meta strip** by selecting them and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>. If you want to edit the clips inside it after grouping them, select your *meta strip* and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You can now apply an *Image Crop* to the *meta strip* in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>). Be sure to check Image Offset. You will also need to change the render dimensions to the correct size.

*Screenshot:*
[image: Screenshot]

You can avoid the need to crop in the video sequence editor entirely by performing the crop in the render dimensions. Simply set the dimensions to the target aspect ratio for you image.

Comment: Cropping the render dimensions sounds like the easiest way to do it, but if I change the Y value to 160 less (in the Properties > Render Presets > Resolution), the video gets squished. I don't seem to know how to change the aspect ratio values to get the desired result. If the video is 1200 x 960 and I want it to be 1200 x 800 (with 160 cut off), how would I set the aspect ratio (currently 1:1!) and resolution?

Comment: Because no matter how I set the values (and check the Crop and Border checkboxes), nothing ever gets cut off, just rescaled inside the new dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to **Properties** > **Render Presets** > **Resolution** and set your preferred resolution. Keep the **Aspect Ratio** to 1:1. Then go to the **Video Sequence Editor** properties panel.

Unchecked the **Image Crop** and Check the **Image Offset** change the value of **X** and **Y** to your own offset.
[image: Uncheck the Image Crop and Check the Image Offset]